# When 2(a+b)+a is negative, which statement must be true?

Tags: linear-algebra

```
A. a<0, b<0
B. a<0, b>0
C. a<-2/3b
D. a<b
```

I know it's probably not a or b, and I think it's c, but I don't know why. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

If $2(a + b) + a < 0$, then $2a + 2b + a < 0$, and so $3a + 2b < 0$. Subtracting $2b$ from both sides of the inequality yields $3a < -2b$. We can now divide both sides by $3$ (a positive number) without affecting the inequality, hence $a < -\frac{2}{3}b$.

Answer (score 0):

@user780985 already showed C is right. We can refute the others with the counterexample $a=0,\,b=-1$.

Comment: Note that options A and B say that $a$ is strictly less than 0.